# What is the difference between dependency injected router and static router in ScalaRouting of Play Framework?

Tags: scala, playframework

What is the difference between the dependency injected router and the static router in ScalaRouting of Play Framework?

Play framework documentation directs dependency injected router is used when a new Play application is created by using the Play seed Activator templates.

But I am still confused about both routers.

If anyone knows, please teach me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In a nutshell**

The dynamic router gives more control over controller instantiation. It allows you to managed dependencies using a dependency injection framework and makes controller testing a lot easier. The static router can be preferred for prototyping as it's setup by default. It's also an obvious choice for the assets as they're also static.

**Extended answer**

It all started with the static router. In Play 2.0 you could create a controller only as a class with static methods (in Java) or as an object (in Scala). It was designed in mind that in MVC controllers are stateless and hence [you don't need multiple instances of such class](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.x/ScalaActions#Controllers-are-action-generators). However, the problem with static methods and objects was that they're hard to unit test, especially mocking or stubbing dependencies was the issue. Dependency injection was also quite painful.

Thanks to positive criticism, [Play 2.1 introduced new mechanism](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Highlights21#Managed-Controller-classes-instantiation) to handle this problem, which allowed dynamic object instantiation. From this point you're able to choose between both route methods by placing `@` before a class name in the routes file.

Before 2.4 dynamic creation was done using a `getControllerInstance()` method in a so-called Global object, but [this mechanism was removed in 2.4](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/GlobalSettings) and replaced by more sophisticated dependency injection approach.

The static router is kept mostly for very simple use cases and because of backward compatibility, yet, for newer projects I would suggest going with the dynamic router as it's free of disadvantages of its predecessor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and detailed explanation :) your answer helped me a lot!