# In Play! Frame work Can I Make classes In models package Singleton?

Tags: java, design-patterns, playframework-2.5

I am new to play! now Play! roughly works on routes, Controllers, and Models. The classes in models are annotated with @Entity which becomes a table in the database, so instead of keeping the methods of classes in models package static  can we make the class it into a Singleton so that I can further implement it with an interface and use it effectively 
And if a class in models package is made singleton is it that it is singleton per session or singleton for the whole app

I will provide some rough example , I cannot post the real code as the company which I am working for doesn't allow me to do so , I am really Sorry for that

old version of the code is as Follows

> Code for MyModelN class in Models package as there are many such Model classes containing the same kind of methods

```
   @Entity   
   @Table(name == "MyModelN")   
   class MyModelN{
     public static String column1;
     public static String column2;
     .............
     public static String coulmnN;

     public static MyModelN findAll(){
         return /*Some JPA code*/
     }
     public static MyModelN findId(){
         return /*Some JPA code*/
     }
      /*And so On*/  
 }
```

> Code For MyControllerN class in Controllers package there are many such controllers

```
  class MyControllerN extends Controller{
    public static Result create(){
      /*Some code which uses the models ...*/
      MyModelN.finAll();  
      return ok();
    }
     /*And so On*/  
 }
```

> Code for the routes file

```
GET           /finance/create               controller.MyControllerN.create()
```

> The above code works fine and serves the purpose , But it contains about 70% code redundant in every controller .So to make it modular and reusable I made an Interface IFinance that extends MyModelN and I made a commonController class which contains the common code of every controller and i wish to use the IFinance handle in the commonController class .......The new version is as follows
>   
>   Code for MyModelN class in Models package as mentioned before (This time no static)

```
   @Entity   
   @Table(name == "MyModelN")   
   class MyModelN implementes IFinance{
     public String column1;
     public String column2;
     .............
     public String coulmnN;

     public MyModelN findAll(){
         return /*Some JPA code*/
     }
     public MyModelN findId(){
         return /*Some JPA code*/
     }
      /*And so On*/  
 }
```

> Code For MyControllerN class in Controllers package as mentioned above (Now no static)

```
  class MyControllerN extends Controller{
    private IFinance iFinance;
    private MyModelN myModelN = new MyModelN();
    private CommonController commonController = new CommonController(myModelN);
    public Result create(){
       /*Some code which uses the models ...*/
       return commonController.createCommon(); 
    }
     /*And so On*/  
 }
```

> Code for CommonController

```
class MyControllerN extends Controller{
    private IFinance iFinance;
    MyControllerN(IFinance iFinance){
     this.iFinance = iFinance;
    }
    public Result createCommon(){
       /*Some code which uses the models ...*/
       iFinance.findAll();
       return ok()
    }
     /*And so On*/  
 }
```

> Code for the routes file is dynamic instead of static

```
GET           /finance/create               @controller.MyControllerN.create()
```

> This works fine for me , here the issue is in every controller I end up making a new object of MyModelN classes whenever I have to use it in Controller,

1. So i was wondering if i could make my MyModelN classes Singleton so that every where i will get the same object and i will not end up creating a lot of objects for the models, As it was working fine with static i think singleton will work but i am not sure about it
2. Now if some MyModelN class is dependent on other `@ManytoOne MyModel1 myModel1` or `@OnetoMany MyModel1 myModel` and I again end up creating new object for that model , so if i make it singleton i will get the same object but will it cause some issues of interference and mixing up of data?
3. I wanted to know how Play handles this internally , when i make a MyModels class Singleton , is it singleton per session or for the whole application , and if its singleton for the whole application then how come so many users use the website simultaneously without their data getting mixed up with other

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some study on Play! framework I would like to answer this question

1. When we make a class singleton which is annotated with @Entity, is it that the Class is singleton per Session or Singleton for the whole app?

   - Yes, Class is Singleton for the whole Application i.e only one instance of the singleton class will be created throughout Application
2. Is it recommended to keep your Models class i.e Class annotated with @Entity Singleton/Static?

   - No, it is not recommended to keep the class Singleton because this can cause data inconsistency when more than one users are using the same @Entity class simultaneously

We must understand that the Play! FrameworkPlay is a stateless, asynchronous, and non-blocking framework that uses an underlying fork-join thread pool to do work stealing for network operations, and can leverage Akka for user level operations.For more Chek this Link [click here](https://www.lightbend.com/blog/why-is-play-framework-so-fast)

So when we use dynamic routes, A new instance of the Controller Class (A Class which extends Play Controller) is created every time the client hits the Controller, For more information [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688504/what-is-the-difference-between-dependency-injected-router-and-static-router-in-s)

But if we make any other Class Singleton, we will get the same instance of the singleton class throughout the application for all/any instance of play controller

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Hey Pushkar I am not very much clear about the question you have asked but I will make an attempt to get as close as possible based on my understanding of your question

so answer the later question first singleton involves using of static so its scope is a across the application life And also so  does the definition of singleton says that only one object of the singleton has to be created across the application. So a class as singleton is singleton accros the application life.

and now coming to the prior question I don't think you should make your model as singleton because of the above mentioned reason. models should be specific to particular session not application.

hope so I answered your query.

Comment: yes but it works fine when the models are completely static , i don't think there should be a problem with singleton , and i think if we make it singleton ... it will be singleton per session but i am not sure about it